# Powershell Split on Degree Symbol

Tags: powershell, split

I am passing in particular strings (Latitude and Longitude) in the Degrees, Minutes, Seconds format.  Is there a way I can do a split on that string for all of the proper symbols?  I can split on ' or " but the degree symbol (°) does not work for splitting.  Is there a workaround or a syntax I need to use?

I also tried the conversion method within Powershell ISE.  I can run the following command:

> [char] 176

and it results in the degree symbol being printed to the output console.  However if I put that in the split parameter in the script, it still gives me the same error (places a ? in between the numbers and complains that the input string is in an incorrect format).

Here is an example of how I was parsing the values:

```
$gps = $gps.Split("'").Split("°").Split("*").Split("’").Split("""").Split("””").Split("?")
```

I have tried replacing the

> "°"

With the following examples:

```
$degSplit = [char]176 and replacing with $degSplit
[char]176 directly
[char]0x00B0
```

All result in the same errors:

> Cannot convert value "38� 9" to type "System.Double". Error: "Input
>   string was not in a correct format."

UPDATE:
I tried the following syntax as suggested below:

```
$option = [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries
$separator = " ", "°", "'", "?", "'", '"', '*'
$gps = $gps.Split($separator,$option)
$gpsDec = [double]$gps[0]
```

I am wanting to create an array of the values inside, to make it easier to convert them to decimal notation.  Still the same error as above.

Here is an example of a value I having streamed in (these are coordinates from a particular column of a CSV that I am importing):

> 39°26'59.75"N

There is a space in the front.  The CSV gets converted from another application and there are 3 spaces for the degrees at all times, to account for a 3-digit degree.  This applies to the Minutes as well (2 digits, even if it is a 7).

UPDATE 2:

Just had a thought.  Is there a better way to do this that is not dependent on syntax or unicode translations?  Is it possible to use regex or some other generic mechanism to just extract all the numbers from the string and assign them to the values of the array?  Something that iterates through each character of the string, if it is numerical, apply it to $gps[0], if the next one is numerical, append it, if not, move on to $gps[1] when we reach the next numerical digit...and so on, until all characters have been evaluated.  Or is this too much overhead?  Unfortunately it would be much easier to just convert it all in the spreadsheet before ingesting the data, but I do not have control over that.

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: I updated the original post.  I didn't realize my post was too vague and I provided more concrete examples and actions I have already tried on my end.

Comment: What is the starting value of `$gps`?  What does `[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($gps)` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with different configurations and syntax versions...provided by the community, I decided to back up a little bit and look at the input itself.  The issue is actually occurring far before the Split method.  The import-csv was not using the proper encoding language for that particular CSV file.  Once I changed the encoding method as such:

```
Import-Csv $global:path'\Spreadsheet.csv' -Encoding Default
```

I was able to parse the data properly.  The encoding converted the degrees symbol to a literal ? character which the Split method could appropriately recognize.  My issue now is that the format of the coordinates are not consistent in the CSV, but that is another issue I need to work through.

UPDATE: I changed it to Default as described below.  This allowed the characters to be encoded properly.

Comment: `Import-Csv $global:path'\Spreadsheet.csv' -Encoding Default` (or `-Encoding OEM`) should retain the `°` _Degree Sign_ symbol unchanged then. The `?`  _Question Mark_ is simply a replacement character for all chars beyond 7-bit `ASCII`.

Comment: You are correct.  I was already tweaking the code for the ? so I need to go back and retweak it to accept the expected characters, but the general idea is the same.  Changing the encoding was the solution.  From the documentation I read, it appeared ASCII was the Default encoding, so it never dawned on me to utilize Default.  Thank you for the tip!

Comment: The [`Import-Csv` docs](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=821815) says  _The default is `ASCII`_  about `-encoding` values. It means that _omitting_ this parameter is the same as using `-encoding ASCII` explicitly. On the other hand, using `-encoding Default` is another thing. You can see the  difference running `[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII` and `[System.Text.Encoding]::Default`.

Comment: That is interesting, since I originally had that entry omitted.  When it was omitted, the degree character was being translated into an error symbol.  When I added the -enconding ASCII field, it changed to a direct '?'.

Comment: The standard replacement symbol `�`  (Unicode `U+FFFD`) is not present in `ASCII`. It appears that **explicit** `-encoding ASCII` applies to **both** input and output whereas **if omitted**, applies to input only **keeping output in Unicode**.

Comment: Really great information for future reference.  Thank you again for the help.  I am glad I was able to get this working with any hacks or bad practices.

Answer (score 3):

Apply .NET [`Split(Char[], StringSplitOptions)` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448(v=vs.110).aspx) as follows:

```
$DmsLatitude  = '51° 28′ 38″ N' # Degree Sign, Prime, Double Prime
$DmsLongitude = @'
    51° 28' 38" E
'@.Trim()                       # Degree Sign, Apostrophe, Quotation Mark

$option    = [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries
$separator = " ", "°", "′", "″", "'", '"'
$DmsLatitude.Split($separator,$option) -join ','
$DmsLongitude.Split($separator,$option) -join ','

<# characters commonly used in DMS coordinates
Char CodePoint         Category Description   
---- ---------         -------- -----------   
   ° U+00B0         OtherSymbol Degree Sign
   ′ U+2032    OtherPunctuation Prime
   ″ U+2033    OtherPunctuation Double Prime
   ° U+00B0         OtherSymbol Degree Sign
   ' U+0027    OtherPunctuation Apostrophe
   " U+0022    OtherPunctuation Quotation Mark
<##>
```

**Output**:

```
PS D:\PShell> D:\PShell\SO\47781745.ps1
51,28,38,N
51,28,38,E

PS D:\PShell>
```

Alternative (newer) link to [`Split(Char[], StringSplitOptions)` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_String_Split_System_Char___System_StringSplitOptions_)

> Syntax (C#)
>
> ```
> [ComVisibleAttribute(false)]
> public string[] Split(
>   char[] separator,
>   StringSplitOptions options
> )
> ```
>
> Parameters
>
> ```
> separator
> ```
>
> Type: `System.Char[]`
>  A character array that delimits the
>   substrings in this string, an empty array that contains no delimiters,
>   or null.
>
> ```
> options
> ```
>
> Type: `System.StringSplitOptions`
>   StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries to omit empty array elements
>   from the array returned; or StringSplitOptions.None to include empty
>   array elements in the array returned.
>
> Return Value
>
> Type: `System.String[]`
>  An array whose elements contain the
>   substrings in this string that are delimited by one or more characters
>   in separator. For more information, see the Remarks section.

Comment: This looks great but still gives the same error.  I think my use case was not properly explained so I updated the original post with more details.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me:

```
PS C:\> $SplitChars = "'", "’", '"', '”', '°', '*', '?';
PS C:\> $gps = @'
 39°26'59.75"N
'@;
PS C:\> $gps.Split($SplitChars, [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries).Trim();
39
26
59.75
N
```

Works for me in the ISE, too, although the ISE does have minor quirks.  I'm on PowerShell 5.0.

---

If the format is always `DDD°DD'DD.DD"A` as you suggest, you can easily do a static mapping:

```
$gps = @'
 39°26'59.75"N
'@;
$gps[0..2] -join '' -as [Decimal]
$gps[4..5] -join '' -as [Decimal]
$gps[7..11] -join '' -as [Decimal]
$gps[13]
```

Comment: I am on Powershell 3.0.  Is this a possible culprit for why it is not working as intended?

Comment: @ChrisMoretti I'm not aware of any issues with String.Split(), but it's certainly possible.

Comment: @ChrisMoretti See my update if the format is as fixed as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably split based on the Char value for the item you want to split on.  I believe [char]248 is degrees.

Check out this page for the values you could use for this. 
https://www.alt-codes.net/

```
$a = [char]176
$test = '33°44°55°'
$test -split $a

33
44
55
```

Comment: I updated the original post to have more direct examples of what I am using and what I have tried so far...  The [char] casting did not work for me when using the .Split method in Powershell.